# Error When Connecting to SQL Server Using SQLAlchemy on Databricks

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, databricks, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server database using SQLAlchemy on a Databricks cluster.

I have some simple code that looks like this,

```
db_conn_str = "mssql+pyodbc://<user-name>:<password>@<server-name>.database.windows.net:1433/<database-name>?driver=SQL Server"

engine = sa.create_engine(db_conn_str)

metadata = sa.MetaData(bind=None)
table = sa.Table(
    table_name,
    metadata,
    autoload=True,
    autoload_with=engine,
    schema=TABLE_SCHEMA
)
```

Note: This code is actually written within a custom Python Package that I am calling from Databricks.

However, I keep getting the following error,

```
DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

What exactly is going on here and how can I resolve this?

Another fact that I think should be mentioned is that usually when connecting to my SQL Server database, I need to whitelist my IP. However, I am not sure how this applies when connecting using Databricks.

Comment: If you run `odbcinst -q -d -n "SQL Server"` does it display a `[SQL Server]` section with (at least) a `Driver=…` entry?

Comment: I cannot seem to run this command. It fails.

Comment: Fails with "odbcinst: SQLGetPrivateProfileString failed with ." ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I tried the answer given here as well, but it does not seem to work for me, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61022848/do-you-know-how-to-install-the-odbc-driver-17-for-sql-server-on-a-databricks-c

Comment: Do you get the same error with `odbcinst -q -d` ?

Comment: Nope. I get this response `[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]`.

Comment: Then use `db_conn_str = "mssql+pyodbc:// … ?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server`

Comment: This worked for me, Gord. The only issue is, this code is contained inside of a custom Python Package that I am calling from Databricks and as a result, if I hard code the driver this way, I become unable to run it locally on my machine.

Comment: Can't you install ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server locally?

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but there are quite a few others contributing to my project. I feel that might be a bit of an issue, since it will break the code when they're running it on their machines. One other option I was thinking of is using `pyodbc.drivers()[0]` to get the available driver on a given machine and append it to the connection string.

Comment: Yes, that's a [good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49736571/2144390). However, on other people's machines you can can't count on the appropriate driver being the first one in the list.

Comment: That is true. I will use one of the options we have looked at here. Thank you very much! Maybe you can add an answer outlining the steps?

Comment: @GordThompson I would really appreciate your feedback on this question as well, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72877663/running-bash-script-in-databricks-fails